# How to bucket/bin the dates in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column with 16 days, 256 days, 450 days as values, which was obtained by subtracting 2 date columns (eg. 2010-11-10 - 2010-11-1). I want to bin the dates into 4 categories (0-30 days as 1, 30-90 days as 2, 90-180 days as 3 and greater than 180 days as 4).

I tried converting the column into categorical and then tried to split the (16 days to '16' and 'days') but got an error.

1. df_merged['Case_Duration'] = df_merged['DateOfResolution'] -df_merged['DateOfRegistration']

#### DateOfRegistration and DateOfResolution are date fields (eg. 2010-11-1)

2. df_merged['Case_Duration'] = df_merged['Case_Duration'].astype('category')

#### to convert 'Case_Duration' column to category

3. df_Days = df_merged["Case_Duration"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)

#### to split the 'Case_Duration' column values. (eg. 16 days -> '16' and 'days')

But this step gives an error -> can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I create a pandas df named `data` with random timestamps at columns `a` and `b` (to represent your initial datetime columns). Column `bucket` has your desired output

```
data_dic = {
    "a": ['2019-07-26 13:21:12','2019-07-26 13:21:12','2019-07-26 13:21:12','2019-07-26 13:21:12'],
    "b": ['2019-03-26 13:21:12','2019-05-26 13:21:12','2019-07-23 13:21:12','2019-02-26 13:21:12'],
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)

data['a'] = pd.to_datetime(data['a'])
data['b'] = pd.to_datetime(data['b'])

data['bucket'] =  np.select( [(data['a'] - data['b']).dt.days< 31, (data['a'] - data['b']).dt.days< 91 ]   ,[1,2], 3)
```

Note that

```
(data['a'] - data['b']).dt.days
```

computes the time difference in days

Comment: @Prateek Ramsinghani Please consider accepting this answer if you find it useful, thank you very much.

Comment: thank you so much sir, it is working perfectly as I wanted it to. I am a beginner at stackoverflow and it does not let beginners to upvote, please consider this comment as an upvote and many thanks from my side !

Comment: @PrateekRamsinghani Thank you very much. I believe you cannot upvote the answer, but ***you can accept it *** (as the asker). You can see the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers